# python.framework.errors_impl.permissiondeniederror

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-classification, inception, windows

I am trying to retrain inception final layer on new set of images. I am using docker TensorFlow image on Windows environment. Below are the steps that I am following.

1. Install docker toolbox for windows.
2. Pulling the tensorflow docker image.

   ```
   docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
   ```
3. Linking tensorflow to the folder on host machine where new set of images are stored.

   ```
   docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/tf_files/samples gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
   ```

   tf_files/samples contains the set of images on which I want to retrain the model.
4. `cd /tensorflow`
5. `git pull`
6. Then I am running the below script.

   ```
   python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
   --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
   --how_many_training_steps 500 \
   --model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
   --output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
   --output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
   --image_dir /tf_files/samples
   ```

Inception model is being downloaded properly but after that I am getting an error which says:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /tf_files/samples
>   /AppData/Local/Application Data; Operation not permitted

Below is the exact error that I am getting.

```
root@54808ee651a1:/tensorflow# python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retra
in.py \
> --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
> --how_many_training_steps 500 \
> --model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
> --output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
> --output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
> --image_dir /tf_files/samples
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 988, in main
    FLAGS.validation_percentage)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 144, in create_image_lists
    sub_dirs = [x[0] for x in gfile.Walk(image_dir)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 518, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 518, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 518, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 499, in walk
    listing = list_directory(top)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 478, in list_directory
    compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /tf_files/samples
/AppData/Local/Application Data; Operation not permitted
```

Comment: did you happen to resolve this error?